# Counting the number of occurrence of a character in a file in case-sensitive way

Tags: c, file, char, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fp1;
    char ch,f[100],c,d;
    int ct=0;

    printf("Enter the file name\n");
    scanf("%s",f);   

    fp1=fopen(f,"r");

    printf("Enter character:");
    scanf(" %c",&c);

    c=toupper(c);

    do 
    { 
       ch=fgetc(fp1);
       d=toupper(ch);
       if(c==d||c==ch)
          ++ct;

    } while(ch!=EOF);

    fclose(fp1);

    printf("\n");
    printf("%d",ct);

    return 0;

}
```

here my file contains `aAaAaA` and when I execute this code, I am getting 6 characters in the file but I should get it as 3 characters because a and A are case insensitive. What's wrong with this code?

Comment: `The condition is a and A are case insensitive`...IMHO, you meant the reverse.

Comment: Check if `fopen` does not return `NULL`. If it does, end the program

Comment: Use `int ch, d, c` otherwise code cannot properly distinguish `EOF` from all other 256 `char`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, essentially, you're incrementing the counter *unconditionally*.

```
if(c==d   ||   c==ch)
      ^            ^
      |            |
UPPERCASE       original
```

will increment the counter for *both* the cases.

As the code is currently written . for an input of `a` or `A`, `c` is **always** `A`, so

- When `a` is read from file, `d` is `A`, so, `c==d` gives TRUE, increments the counter
- When `A` is read from file, `ch` is `A`, so as `d` thereby `c==d` gives TRUE, increments the counter.

What you actually want is to consider the input as **case-sensitive** [`A` and `a` should be counted as differnt characters.]

Also, as Mr. **@coolguy** mentioned in his comments, check the return value of `fopen()` for success before using the returned pointer.

Solution:

1. Do not convert the input using `toupper()`. Use the actual input instead.
2. If you want case-sensible operation, *only* check for the input by user and input from file, without any case-conversion. A pseudocode may look like

.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include<ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp1 = NULL;
    char ch,f[100],c,d;
    int ct=0;

    printf("Enter the file name\n");
    scanf("%s",f);   

    fp1=fopen(f,"r");

    if (!fp)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file for reading\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    printf("Enter character:");
    scanf(" %c",&c);

    do 
    { 

        ch=fgetc(fp1);

        if(ch == c)
            ++ct;

    }while(ch!=EOF);

    fclose(fp1);    
    printf("%d\n",ct);    
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: @WeatherVane Don't make me panic mate. :-) English is neither my native language nor I'm fluent in it. So my interpretation is correct, right?

Comment: Perfect, yes indeed. I deleted my earlier comment as soon as I spotted me wrongity. But you saw it anyway!

Comment: @WeatherVane Please don't mind, just wanted to be sure. thanks anyways. ;-)

Comment: Just wanted to note with regards to your second bullet point, `c==ch` doesn't actually get evaluated because `c==d` is still true, and in fact always true for this input because `c` and `d` are always uppercase.

Comment: @mstbaum Thanks for pointing that out. I'll update accrodingly.

Comment: Note: this code may fail in a number of ways should 1) `c < 0`, 2) User enters space `' '` for the character 3) file contains character `(char) EOF`.  Likely none of these are a big concern for OP.  Suggest `int ch; unsigned char uc = c; while((ch = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF) if (ch == uc) ct++; }`.